# Select2 start searching after first N characters using ajax

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I don't want to call ajax request if user input only one character in search field.

Request should be called only if user doesn't input characters or input 3 and more characters. Does select2 have this settings?

javascript

```
this.$('#users').select2({
          ajax: {
            url: 'http://my-domain.local/api/web/users',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function(params) {
              var query;
              query = {
                search: params.term,
                limit: 20,
                group_id: viewTemplateData["group_id"]
              };
              return query;
            },
            processResult: function(data) {
              return {
                results: data
              };
            }
          },
          templateResult: function(data) {
            return '<option value="${data.id}">' + data.name + '</option>';
          },
          templateSelection: this._sanitize_text,
          placeholder: I18n.t('assign_to_group')
        });
```